# Refresh or update content page every few seconds automatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using `Xamarin.forms` (`PCL`) and I need to refresh/update Content Page with its data every few seconds.  The data is retrieved from `API` in the `viewmodel`.

Is there any method or handler that can be used periodically to call the `Get Api` periodically inside the `page.xaml.cs`, something like:

```
methodRunPeriodically()
{
 userdata = await UserService.GetUserasync(_UserViewModel.EmployeeId);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the code in the above question, you would ensure that:

1. Your userdata object implements IPropertyChange as follows:

   ```
   //Other usings skipped for brevity
   ...
   ...
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

   // This is a simple user class that 
   // implements the IPropertyChange interface.
   public class DemoUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       // These fields hold the values for the public properties.
       private string userName = string.Empty;
       private string phoneNumber = string.Empty;

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
       // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
       // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
       private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           }
       }

       public DemoUser()
       {
       }
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string UserName
       {
           get
           {
               return this.userName;
           }

           set
           {
               if (value != this.userName)
               {
                   this.userName = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
       }

       public string PhoneNumber
       {
           get
           {
               return this.phoneNumber;
           }

           set
           {
               if (value != this.phoneNumber)
               {
                   this.phoneNumber = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your ContentPage, you then try the following, (I slightly modified the code by others above):

   ```
   public class UserPage : ContentPage
   {
       private DemoUser demoUser;
       private int intervalInSeconds;

       public UserPage()
       {
           //Assuming this is a XAML Page....
           InitializeComponent();
       }
       public UserPage(DemoUser demoUser, int intervalInSeconds = 10) : this()
       {
           this.demoUser = demoUser;
           this.intervalInSeconds = intervalInSeconds;

           this.BindingContext = this.demoUser; 

           Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.intervalInSeconds), () =>
           {
               Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => refreshDemoUser());
               return true;
           });
       }

       private async void refreshDemoUser()
       {
           this.demoUser = await getDemoUserById(this.demoUser.Id);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 13):

Xamarin.Forms has an API for starting a timer that you might find useful for this, documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/p/System.TimeSpan/System.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D/).

```
Device.StartTimer (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () => {
    // If you want to update UI, make sure its on the on the main thread.
    // Otherwise, you can remove the BeginInvokeOnMainThread
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => methodRunPeriodically());
    return shouldRunAgain;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows to run a Task when 10 seconds has passed. Returning `true` in `Device.StartTimer` will ensure that the `Timer` keeps running. Also, you want to ensure that you invoke the method on the main thread to update the UI:

```
public MyConstructor()
{
    StartTimer();
}

private void StartTimer()
{
    Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () => 
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(UpdateUserDataAsync);
        return true;
    });
}

private async void UpdateUserDataAsync()
{
    userdata = await UserService.GetUserasync(_UserViewModel.EmployeeId);
}
```

If your API doesn't expose an `EventHandler` that you can subscribe to, then you need to do as mentioned in my example above.

Comment: System.Threading.Timer is typically not available in Xamarin.Forms PCL compatible profiles.

Comment: True. Updated my answer.

Comment: It's better to use the bindings built into Xamarin.Forms to handle the UI updates. In this example, no updates will happen on the UI thread unless everything is bound to `userdata` and the setter calls `OnPropertyChanged`. If that is the case, then `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should just bind the UI to properties in your ViewModel and then set those properties appropriately. Calling `OnPropertyChanged()` will trigger Xamarin.Forms to update the UI based on the bound properties. Something like below:

```
//Code in Page
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        var entry = new Entry();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();

        entry.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Entry.TextProperty, vm=>vm.EntryText);
        Content = entry;
    }
}

//Code in ViewModel
public class MyViewModel() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> methodRunPeriodically());
    }

    string entryText;
    public string EntryText
    {
        get { return entryText; }
        set
        {
            if(entryText == value)
                return;
            entryText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    bool shouldRun = true;
    async Task methodRunPeriodically()
    {
        while(shouldRun)
        {
            userdata = await UserService.GetUserasync(_UserViewModel.EmployeeId);
            EntryText = userdata.FirstName;
            await Task.Delay(5000); //Run this every 5 seconds
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In this pattern, we are kicking off a long-running task that will run in a loop. It is reaching out to refresh the `userData` every 5 seconds and then setting the `EntryText` property. In the setter of the `EntryText` property in our ViewModel, we are calling `OnPropertyChanged()` which will cause Xamarin.Forms to update the UI. Calling `OnPropertyChanged()` triggers Xamarin.Forms to switch thread context from the background task to the UI thread and then back to the background task.

I didn't write this in XAML, but the binding would be pretty much the same except the entry would be like below:

```
<Entry Text={Binding EntryText}/>
```

#### EDIT

[@therealjohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454417/therealjohn)'s answer is good also. You could use that instead of my while loop like below:

```
bool shouldRun = true;
methodRunPeriodically()
{
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => 
    {
        userdata = await UserService.GetUserasync(_UserViewModel.EmployeeId);
        EntryText = userdata.FirstName;
        return shouldRun;
    });
}
```

You can review what the Forms source code is doing with the `Device.StartTimer` on the native [iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9535315986c6ad5d51ec28f676310b9a5f7d444c/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Forms.cs) and [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d43b8a2da6681518b6b765f748a79b5fcf5927ac/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Forms.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Update UI every one second:

```
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), loop2);
        bool loop2()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => updateUI());
            return true;
        }
```

or:

```
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), loop2);
        bool loop2()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                updateUI();
                //more stuff;
            });
            return true;
        }
```