# xamarin forms listview auto refresh

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and I'm making a Listview that needs to update every time I insert new information in the database, so far I can display the info of my list and add it via a PHP file but I can't make it refresh automatically.

```
namespace Proyect
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Alarms : ContentPage
    {
        public Alarms ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
            AlarmsList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Cells.AlarmsCell));   //Template of the Alarms
            this.LoadAlarms();
        }

        private async void LoadAlarms()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://192.168.0.13");  
                string url = string.Format("/Proyect/alarmscode.php?");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var jsonalarms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<GetAlarms>>(result);
                AlarmsList.ItemsSource = jsonalarms;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("ERROR", e + "", "OK");
                return;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a timer or some sort of scheduled task to periodically request updated information from your server?

Comment: It will be very easy if you will use MVVM -> just periodically update the alarms property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh ListView in ContentPage in xamarin forms periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548006/how-to-refresh-listview-in-contentpage-in-xamarin-forms-periodically)

Comment: I understand that if I use an ObservableCollection<T> as my ItemSource the listview will automatically update  whenever items are added or removed from it and Im think thats what im doing. It didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to keep the same ObservableCollection and update its content instead of setting a new ObservableCollection every time?

```
namespace Proyect
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Alarms : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<GetAlarms> _itemsSource = null;

    public Alarms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AlarmsList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Cells.AlarmsCell));   //Template of the Alarms

        _itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<GetAlarms>();
        AlarmsList.ItemsSource = _itemsSource;

        this.LoadAlarms();
    }

    private async void LoadAlarms()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://192.168.0.13");
            string url = string.Format("/Proyect/alarmscode.php?");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var jsonalarms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<GetAlarms>>(result);

            _itemsSource.Clear();
            foreach (var alarm in jsonalarms)
            {
                _itemsSource.Add(alarm);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("ERROR", e + "", "OK");
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 10), () => {
            // do something every 10 seconds

```
        return true; // runs again, or false to stop
    });
```

Comment: hey, thanks. I tried that and It works but it´s not exacltly what Im looking for. Is It possible to just refresh the listview when a new item is added?