# Xamarin polling without stuck

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, polling

I am implementing an APP with Xamarin.

The app need to refresh data through Wi-Fi with device and show new data on screen.

But when polling triggered. The app always stuck for few seconds.

```
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        //Show new data when entering this page
        await Polling();


    }

    async Task Polling()
    {
        await Read_Data();
        Show_Data();
    }
```

How could I do this without stuck. Make the app polling smoothly?

I want to call the Polling() every 30 seconds.

Thank you!

Comment: use a Timer and a background task

Comment: Use Timer and change the UI on main thread , check the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574642/refresh-or-update-content-page-every-few-seconds-automatically.